# Generating very large prime numbers C++

Tags: c++, loops, primes

Here is the simple code i wrote (I know I could optimize it, but I was doing some test and found an issue):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n;
    int d=3;
    cout<<"insert a number n: ";
    cin>>n;
    while (d<n){
        if ((n%d)!=0) {
            d=d+2;
        }
        else
        n=n+1;
    }
    cout<<"the number: "<<n<<" is prime"<<endl;
    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Basically it seams to be working for "small enough" numbers (i.e. numbers less than '2147483647') here is a screenshot of what is going on in the output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35pHy.jpg)

I need to generate a prime with about one thousand digits (or maybe a few more, but we're somewhere in that range 500-1000)
Can c++ handle it? (also i need the program to loop it for me as in my code) Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

Comment: You are going to need a Big Int library like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/)

Comment: Such large numbers can't be held in an `int` variable. You might want to inform yourself about the limits [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits).

Comment: Have you done any research on generating large primes? From a quick google search, it looks like you may want to read up on our sister site for cryptography [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/71)

Comment: A common trick is to use modular arithmetic to avoid the problem of huge numbers entirely. See if your assignment specification allows for this or similar alternatives .

Comment: look at: https://www.sanfoundry.com/cpp-program-implement-miller-rabin-primality-test/

your current approach (even if made to work with 1000digit numbers) will take years to give an answer. maybe you can adapt the linked test to use huge numbers.

Comment: @skeller found that page very useful, I do have another question, even "long long" seems to be too small for any similar imput, what's the best way around it? do I have to convert my number into a string, or, I also found on some forums people talking about "C++ large-number packages"... I do apologize for asking rather odd questions but I have done only a few of programming at school

Comment: @SpasojeDurovic https://gmplib.org/ could be an option. If you just need the primes, use a library that does that. if its an excersise, use a big int lib like the linked one or start with smaller size numbers. do not apologize for asking questions - that is how one learns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using 'long' or 'long long' also you can use 'unsigned' for bigger range since int also uses negative numbers which you don't need to get prime numbers.

Comment: Asker wants around a thousand digits. `long long` is not nearly long enough on any computer I'm aware of.